# Webi Report aggregation produces incorrect variance for all data

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a query regarding report-level aggregation.

Let's say my report contains 3 columns that give the sum of revenue in actuals, in budget and variance for different sector. I load the values in the granular level like for an area, product, year.

Now the problem is:

- When I drill down and select at granular level I get the values correctly.
- But at higher level, that is for **all regions**, for **all products**, for **all years** in **all areas** my value differs for the variance.

What can be the cause of this? Can anyone please help in this concern?

Thanks
Niki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is when you aggregate to a higher level, as is the case in your example, any calculation you do will also be done with the aggregated values of that level.

Example:

- Retrieve *year* and *month* from the database, as well as the *average value of sales revenue*.
- Now create a table in your report with only *year* and the *average value of sales revenue*.

The result will likely be wrong. Why? The average value is calculated using *year* and *month* as dimensions. Thus, if you remove one dimension, WebI will aggregated all measures (in this case the average value) according to the *projection aggregation* function in your universe. This is usually *Sum*.

In other words, when you remove the *month* dimension and only report on year, you get a sum of the individual average values.

You can solve this by changing your *projection aggregation* for that measure to *database delegated*. This means that whenever the dimensions change, the measure value will be invalidated (*#TOREFRESH* appears) and you need to refresh the query in order to allow WebI to send the calculation back to the database.

Using *calculation contexts* you can change how a measure is calculated (in-report that is) by specifying the input and output dimensions for the aggregation. However, in case of an average, this won't solve the issue, as you need to recalculate the measure on database level.

Calculation contexts are an advanced topic of Web Intelligence, and are explained in detail with examples in the *Using functions, formulas and calculations in Web Intelligence* [manual](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_ffc_user_guide_en.pdf), in chapter 4: *Understanding calculation contexts*.